# Python ImportError No module named crypto.PublicKey.RSA

Tags: python

When I try to execute a python program, I get this from terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "ring.py", line 1, in <module>
import os, hashlib, random, crypto.PublicKey.RSA
ImportError: No module named crypto.PublicKey.RSA
```

I have no idea how to solve this and other questions have proven completely useless to my situation.

Is the module there but in the wrong place?
Should I download modules from somewhere like for node.js?
Or it's more like Java?

Comment: after successfully installing crypto (thanks guys) now unfortunately the error just shifted to No module named PublicKey.RSA

Comment: I even installed the package from the tar.gz after downloading it from the website. But still nothing

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The correct package to install is pycrypto.

```
pip install pycrypto
```

Should work on most platforms, otherwise get Pip from https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/

Edit: As mentioned in the comments below, `pip install pycryptodome` installs a newer, drop-in replacement for pycrypto and is the better option going forward.

Comment: Now I think pycryptodome is the more generally used one.

Answer (score 14):

If you are using Python 3.7, it *already exists*. Just change the folder name in C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages
from **crypto** to **Crypto**

Comment: Hello sir, I have checked the folder path, but the 'Crypto' folder doesn't exist. What to do in this case? looking forward to here from you.

Answer (score 4):

Rename crypto directory under “Lib/site-packages” to Crypto, then importing will work.

Comment: Hello sir, I have checked the folder path, but the 'Crypto' folder doesn't exist. What to do in this case? looking forward to here from you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have to install it. Try this from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
pip install crypto
```

For `mac`, try to use `easy_install`.

```
sudo easy_install python-pip
pip install crypto
```

If `crypto` is installed properly, import like below:

```
 from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
```

Comment: It's important to know what if using Python 3.x you need to specify `pip3`, for Ubuntu at least.

Comment: what about mac? i don't have apt-get here

Comment: Do you have `easy_install`?

Comment: Yes. I just managed to install Crypto with easy_install. Now the error is just  ImportError: No module named PublicKey.RSA

Comment: @user3753342 Try `from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA`, hope this will work for you.

Comment: It does not... :C Thank you very much anyway Ahsanul!

Comment: installing crypto didn't work for me : Fredrik Håård's answer below did: `pip install pycrypto`

Comment: @datakid use `pip install cryptodome` if you are on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Install Pycryptodome using `python3 -m pip install pycryptodome`. `crypto.PublicKey.RSA` is not proper, instead try using `from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA`.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and reinstalling worked for me.

```
py -m pip uninstall pycryptodome
```

then

```
py -m pip install pycryptodome
```